# Php mailer error: SMTP error

Tags: php

I am using php mailer class. I am getting : 
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: s_deshmukh88@hotmail.com

```
$mail = new phpMailer();
$body             = "Hello, this is a test mail.";
//$body             = preg_replace('/\\\\/','', $body); //Strip backslashes

$mail->IsSMTP();                           // tell the class to use SMTP
//$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
//$mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP server port
$mail->Host       = "localhost";           // SMTP server
$mail->Username   = "localhost";     // SMTP server username
$mail->Password   = "password";            // SMTP server password
//$mail->SMTPSecure   = "tls";
//$mail->IsSendmail();  // tell the class to use Sendmail

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@domain.com","First Last");

$mail->From       = "name@domain.com";
$mail->FromName   = "First Last";

$to = "s_deshmukh88@hotmail.com";

$mail->AddAddress($to);

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->WordWrap   = 80; // set word wrap

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

if($mail->Send()){
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }
```

What can be the reason ?

Comment: Do you get this as a return value from the function or is it sent to you from the postmaster of the target domain through an email?

Comment: @slugonamission Considering there is no error message being printed in the code above, I'm guessing it's a bounce email from the target domain...

Comment: no no..this error I am getting through phpmailer class. So it not from target domain.

Comment: is this an error because SMTP was not properly configured? I saw a link where it was mentioned that openSSL is required. I installed openSSL and tried to generate certificate as was mentioned in that link, but to no avail. An error occurs `The ordinal 947 could not be located in the dynamic link library LIBEAY32.dll`. So far I am unable to send mail using phpmailer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem using authenticated SMTP.  When I tested my mailing from home using xampp but connected to a (shared) server, emails went to users without problems.  When I tried the same thing with the PHP on the host server, emails went through to addresses on my account but NOT to external addresses.  (Ie. if my address is fred@bloggs.com and I send an email to fred@bloggs.com, it goes through but if I send it to jim@smith.com, it fails)  The solution turned out to be to use the full host address when working on my local pc, ie $mail->Host = "mail.fred.bloggs.com", but $mail->Host = "localhost" on the server.  May seem perverse but it works.

Answer (score 5):

Just try to put SMTPAuth to false and Host to'localhost'.

Thanks !! :)

Comment: By making above 2 changes my server is able to send email. Thanks @user182925

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue, and in my case, i believe it was the webhost's mail server that was not allowing a non-matching domain name for the From address.  So for example, i was using mail.mydomain.com to send mail, but i wanted the from address to be test@test.com
When i switched the from address to test@mydomain.com, then the email was getting sent.

Comment: I change mail server to "localhost", the issue solved.